# How do I count the frequency of words in a sorted list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
npl = []
for i in df2['Review']:
    npl.extend(tb(i).noun_phrases)
```

This is the code I used to produce my list and it's very long.

```
['omg',
 'populus scramble',
 'coffee',
 'hack',
 'snagged',
 'burpple',
 'ice cream melts',
 'sweet prize ',
 ...]
```

Basically, how do I develop a code that will loop the list to count the frequency of words and show the words too? Something like Counter. I spent hours looking through this website, trying to find a code that works for me but to no avail.

```
npl.count('coffee')
```

Using the code above works but it's only applicable for one word

Expected output is something like this:

```
 {'coffee', '45'
  'snagged', '23'
  'ice cream melts', '13'}
```

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Comment: Updated it already, basically just most frequent word with accompanying number

Comment: Why can't you just do `Counter(npl)` ?

Comment: @RafaelIC Oh, I'm dumb! Yea that output works, but that's half of my problem solved. Now I'm left with the count of words from highest to lowest

Comment: Use `Counter(npl).most_common()` to get it sorted

Comment: Yup! I got it sorted now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Counter from Library collections on a dataframe as follow :

```
word_counter = Counter()
df2['Review'].str.split(" ").apply(word_counter.update)
```

But as you have a list, you can directly apply it to the list:

```
word_counter = Counter("your list")
```

After you can loop thru index and remove some stopwords if you want. You can also see the most common ones by doing `word_counter.most_common(10)`

But be carefull that you result wont be perfect due to multiple writing like house or houses. The best would be to tokenize and apply a stemmer first.

#### Edit1

If you want a dictionnary of the most commons one, you can do:

```
dict(word_counter .most_common(10))
```

This is my snippet:

```
from collections import Counter

inp = list("abcaddabcabadbcabdabdcbaziyutoigkfdshjkbvaoiuhgbgjkvd^giohdfb")
word_counter = Counter(inp)

dict(word_counter.most_common(4)) => {'a': 9, 'b': 10, 'c': 4, 'd': 8}
```

Comment: I tried your code above and there is nothing for me. It looks something like this:

`0      None
1      None
2      None
3      None
4      None
5      None
6      None
7      None
8      None
9      None
10     None
11     None`

Comment: Nevermind what I said earlier. After playing around with what you provided, it works. Your code is definitely what I was looking for. I got my answer here thank you!

Comment: maybe because I splitted on "-" instead of space " " (sorry I copy pasted it from a code where I wanted to split by "-"). This is fixed. Thanks for accepting the answer btw :)